# How to import axios globally to a vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I just installed `axios` to my vue project as

```
npm install axios
```

then in `main.js` file I import it as

```
import axios from "axios";
```

**But when I use axios** in my components, it says

> ReferenceError: axios is not defined

that means each and every component I have to import axios.

Is there a smart way to import `axios` **globally to my vue project**.
Then I won't need to import it on components each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

The power of Vue has much to do with the state management(getters, mutations and actions). [Here's a good overview](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-state-management-with-vuex-introduction-db26cb495113)

I recommend you to do your axios call inside the actions, as they're executed asynchronously and you won't see your app freezing while doing your calls.